# Implement different search method for JQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datapicker

I have this table with different columns and search box:

### [image]

For the column with date value i use in the search box the datepicker js.
Instead for other column i use the default search box of Datatable.

I have the need to diversify the search, through the range of dates, or just text. But the search method is seems to be unique and can not have different implementations.

Thanks.

I have this situation:

```
    $(.datepicker, this.footer()).on('apply.datepicker',function (ev,picker){
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + '|' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');)

        if(that.search() !== (picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + '|' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'))){
                that.search(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + '|' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY')).draw();
        }
    }
```

and

```
    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's close to how I implemented my search.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on what you mean by "I have the need to diversify the search, through the range of dates, or just text"? What exactly are you trying to do? As written it's unclear what you need.

Comment: I want a search for date and search for a basic text.
In this case in the first column i use a range of date..instead in second column i use a string for my search.

Comment: You can try my yadcf plugin for that... see showcase pages http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/ and http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_bootstrap.html , also read docs in the yadcf js file, its very powerful IMO